# Does the "Hits can't be evaded" from The Tempesteous Steel work for both weapons when dual wielding?

Tags: path-of-exile

[The Tempestuous Steel](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_Tempestuous_Steel) is a unique sword with the "Hits can't be evaded" property, does this mean that if I dual wield this sword that my other weapon will never miss? Or does it only work for the sword itself and can my other weapon still miss?

Comment: Judging from the similar mod on the unique shield Lycosidae, I think it's global, but I'm not certain enough to answer such. They are worded slightly differently, and with GGG that can make all the difference. OFC, if it's local, there are several other methods to never miss an attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod "Hits can't be evaded" from The Tempestuous Steel is a local mod. If you dual wield it, hits from your second weapon may still miss.

[This Website](http://poedb.tw/us/unique.php?n=The_Tempestuous_Steel) is a possibility to check, if you are unsure, wether a mod on any item is local or global.